# How to Setup two ISPs on One Mikrotik Router

Tags: isp

I have One Mikrotik router running router OS v6.1. I have One ISP connected to it but i recently got another ISP as backup. I want to connect the second ISP to the router in such a way that if the first ISP fails, the second one will kick in immediately. The link from both ISPs are ethernet links> Does anybody have any idea how to do this ?.

Comment: Have you sen [this mikrotik wiki entry](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Advanced_Routing_Failover_without_Scripting)?

Comment: Are you hosting any sites?  Do you own any public IP space?

Comment: @Avery, No, I just have an application server that branches connect to. Yes i have a /29 class c address from both ISPs. I already solved this problem. It wasnt that difficult to figure out once i went into the Mikrotik router. I just configured 2 static routes with different admin distances. The main ISP with a lower admin distance and a ping check on it so that once it goes down, the second ISP kicks in. Thanks for your concern though.

Answer (score 4):

It wasnt that difficult to figure out once i went into the Mikrotik router. I just configured 2 static routes pointing towards the ISPs with different administrative distances. The main ISP with a lower administrative distance and a ping check on it so that once it goes down, the second ISP kicks in. To this, i logged into the Mikrotik router with winbox and went to IP tab. I chose routes from the drop down menu. The rest was self explanatory. After configuring it, i pulled the cable from ISP1 and PCs on the LAN were still able to surf the internet. I ran a tracert 4.2.2.2 which returned the backup ISP's router. I plugged the cable from ISP1 back into the router and immediately ran a tracer 4.2.2.2 which returned ISP1's router. Thanks  everybody for your help.

Comment: It's working, but if primary ISP lost internet it can keep link and active gateway, so soute over  secondary ISP not activated.
For smarter routes switching is better to use script and sheduler or netwatch.

Comment: @mmv-ru, it happens like u said - at times if the default gateway is still reachable but internet is down at the isp end, router wont switch to the second gateway. I really dont know much about script, scheduler and netwatch.

Comment: its too long to make soficticated reply, because there no one perfect solution.
Try start from http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Failover_via_Netwatch_III_%28English%29
and 
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Failover_Scripting

Answer (score 0):

it was my problem too.
you should create tow static route:
one of them referred to ISP1 and another to ISP2 , but ISP1's distance is 1 and ISP2's distance is 2.
in this situation all client go out through ISP1 and if ISP1 is failed it is transferred to 
ISP2 .
I wish you good luck.

Comment: depends on how it fails. if the link is still up, it hasn't "failed". You'd have to setup some sort of health monitor to detect when the gateway is unreachable.